# Why isn't g++ linking to the designated -L path correctly?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I have tried the -L command to change the linker search directly and I have even tried both -Wl,-rpath,/mydir and -Wl,-rpath-link,/mydir however g++ still just seems to be searching in /usr/bin/ld.  What am I doing wrong here?  Sorry if something is blatantly wrong as I am new to compiling without an IDE.

Makefile I am currently using.

```
    #Makefile for compiling library.
CC       = g++
CURNTDIR = $(shell pwd)
IFLAG    = -I$(CURNTDIR)/include
LFLAG    = -L$(CURNTDIR)/lib
LIBS     = -llibSDLmain -llibSDL2
CXXFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath,$(CURNTDIR)/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,$(CURNTDIR)/lib
objs     = SpiceMain.o SystemHandler.o

SpiceMain: $(objs)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(IFLAG) $(LFLAG) $(objs) $(LIBS)

SpiceMain.o: SpiceMain.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(IFLAG) $(LFLAG) $? $(LIBS)

SystemHandler.o: SystemHandler.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(IFLAG) $(LFLAG) $? $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm $(objs)
    rm SpiceMain
```

Returned error in terminal.

```
g++ -o SpiceMain -Wl,-rpath,/home/harry/Desktop/programs/spiceengine/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/harry/Desktop/programs/spiceengine/lib -I/home/harry/Desktop/programs/spiceengine/include -L/home/harry/Desktop/programs/spiceengine/lib SpiceMain.o SystemHandler.o -llibSDLmain -llibSDL2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibSDLmain
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibSDL2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:11: SpiceMain] Error 1
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to leave off the "lib*" prefix (and *.so suffix):

```
-L/my/library/path -lSDLmain -lSDL2
```

Comment: That was actually the simplest thing in the world and the only thing I didn't try.  Thank you so much.  Its always the smallest things that stop a project.

Comment: If it's not clear, this is because an `-lFOO` flag means to search for "libFOO.so" or "libFOO.a" (or whatever other platform-specific suffixes might apply). So `-llibSDLmain` was searching for "liblibSDLmain.so" or "liblibSDLmain.a".